# Joining temp tables with different structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 temp tables. One has data column wise.

```
OrderCode   OrderType
ABC         1000
```

One has data row wise

```
FieldName   Value
ORDER_CODE  ABC
ORDER_TYPE  2000
```

I need to write a query that essentially joins both of them and updates the value if it exists in table 2.

Recordset result needs to be

```
OrderCode  OrderType
ABC        2000
```

EDIT-

If there are 2 orders in table 1 with the same order code:

```
OrderCode   OrderType
ABC         1000
ABC     5000
```

the result set will need to be

```
   OrderCode   OrderType
   ABC         2000
   ABC         2000
```

Comment: If there are two orders in the Table2, how do you distinguish between them?

Comment: If there are two orders in the first table, I will need to update it as well. Edited as an ex

Comment: Ok, but in table2, how dow you distinguish between different order codes? If you have two orders with codes ABC and DEF, how do you put ORDER_CODE for them into the row-wise table?

Comment: Its guaranteed to be only 1 in table2

Comment: Yes, it will work if there is only one ORDER_CODE and ORDER_TYPE in table2.

Answer (score 1):

To select the rowset:

```
SELECT  tt1.ordercode, tt2_type.Value
FROM    Table2 AS tt2_code
JOIN    Table1 tt1
ON      tt1.orderCode = tt2_code.value
JOIN
        Table2 AS tt2_type
ON      tt2_type.fieldName = 'ORDER_TYPE'
WHERE   tt2_code.fieldName = 'ORDER_CODE'
```

To update `Table1` based on values from `Table2`:

```
WITH q AS
    (
    SELECT  tt1.ordercode, tt2_type.Value
    FROM    Table2 AS tt2_code
    JOIN    Table1 tt1
    ON      tt1.orderCode = tt2_code.value
    JOIN
            Table2 AS tt2_type
    ON      tt2_type.fieldName = 'ORDER_TYPE'
    WHERE   tt2_code.fieldName = 'ORDER_CODE'
    )
UPDATE q
SET    oldvalue = newvalue
```

This is one of the cases where `JOIN`-less syntax is more legible.

Comment: In the FROM clause, what is tt2?

Comment: Me thinks that should be Table2

Comment: Cool, will this query work in the 2nd scenario (Pls see Edit)

Comment: Quassnoi - I am trying to rewrite using INNER JOINs and am unable to get it work. Could you give me an ex of how to do this using the INNER JOIN syntax?

Comment: Quassnoi - SQL Server 2008 will have the joinless syntax obsolete. Using the join syntax is one of our dev guidelines. Any help is appreciated

Comment: WHERE will not be obsolete even in SQL Server 2028, if it will still be called _SQL_ Server. How will you filter the rows if you don't have any joins? There are cases when you can't completely get rid of WHERE, this being one of these cases.

Comment: You may put a CROSS JOIN instead of comma between Table1 and Table2 if you want, but I don't see any point in this.